# Is AI Gym's action and state data normalized?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to implement a DDPG agent to control the [Gym's Pendulum](https://www.gymlibrary.ml/environments/classic_control/pendulum/).
Since I am new to gym, I was wondering if the state data collected via `env.step(action)` is already normalized or I should do that manually. Also, should `action` be normalized or in the [-2, 2] range?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env.step(action)` returns tuple (`observation`, `reward`, `done`, `info`). If you're referring to data in `observation`, then answer is no, it's not normalized (all with accordance to [observation space](https://www.gymlibrary.ml/environments/classic_control/pendulum/#observation-space) section: three coordinates with values in [-1; 1] for the first two and [-8; 8] for the last one). `action` should be normalized to [-2; 2] range, though it'll be [addinionally clipped](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/pendulum.py#L118) to this range.